# Spacy: count occurrence for specific token in each sentence

Tags: nlp, counter, spacy, find-occurrences, spacy-3

I want to count the occurrence of the token *and* for each sentence in a corpus using spacy and append the result for each sentence to a list.  Until now the code bellow returns the total number (for the whole corpus) regarding *and*.

Example/Desired output for 3 sentences : ['1', '0', '2']
Current output : [3]

```py
doc = nlp(corpus)
nb_and = []
for sent in doc.sents:
    i = 0
    for token in sent:
        if token.text == "and":
            i += 1
            nb_and.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append `i` to `nb_and` after each sentence is processed:

```py
for sent in doc.sents:
    i = 0
    for token in sent:
        if token.text == "and":
            i += 1
    nb_and.append(i)
```

Test code:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
corpus = "I see a cat and a dog. None seems to be unhappy. My mother and I wanted to buy a parrot and a tortoise."
doc = nlp(corpus)
nb_and = []
for sent in doc.sents:
    i = 0
    for token in sent:
        if token.text == "and":
            i += 1
    nb_and.append(i)

nb_and
# => [1, 0, 2]
```